Quasar qpopup edit async validation not working
I am facing issue with qpopupedit async validation I created a  codepen. I think it is converting return boolean value to a string. can anyone check why it is not working ?
I created a Codepen you can check
async function validatecalories (val){
      errorCalories.value = true;
      errorMessageCalories.value = 'async error';
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function (){
          reject(false); 
          }, 300);
      });
    }


The question needs to contain all the necessary code besides the link to a demo. :validate="async (val)=> validatecalories" is a mistake because you return a function instead of  a value, and "validate" doesn't seem to support async any way, so you need to return a value of a ref that is constantly updated on model updates
